# passing command line arguments to a shell script doesn't work

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, csh

I want to write a script that will change to different directories depending on my input. something like this:

```
test.sh:
#!/bin/bash
ssh machine001 '(chdir ~/dev$1; pwd)'
```

But as I run `./test.sh 2` it still goes to `~/dev`. It seems that my argument gets ignored. Am I doing anything very stupid here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bash ignores any variable syntax inside the single-quoted(') strings. You need double quotes(") in order to make a substitution:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh machine001 "(chdir ~/dev$1; pwd)"
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter is enclosed in single quotes, so it isn't expanded on the local side. Use double-quotes instead.

```
#!/bin/bash

ssh machine001 "chdir ~/dev$1; pwd"
```

There's no need for the `(...)`, since you are only running the pair of commands then exiting.